# Declaración de nuevos tipos de datos

Tags: c

disculpen, aun no entiendo bien estructuras de datos y tengo un problema con esta definición

```
typedef int (*tipo_ap_fun) (int, int);
```

Se supone que ya se creó un nuevo tipo dato (que en este caso sería un dato tipo apuntador a función), mi pregunta es que si pueden haber "otros" nuevos tipos de datos aparte de los apuntadores que pueda declarar, algo como

```
typedef int (*int) (int, int);
typedef double (*float) (int, int);
```

Comment: Lo que esta dentro del (*) es el nombre que tu le das al tipo. Entonces no pueden haber como las segundas que pones, ya que a un tipo no le puedes colocar el nombre de un primitivo

Comment: Puedes usar `typedef` para crear un tipo a partir de un `struct`.

Comment: Puedes usar `typedef` con cualquier tipo de dato, pero tienes que usar un nombre que no exista y un tipo de dato que ya exista...

Comment: Ok ok, entonces sólo existe la opción de que si pongo int (*) x, x sea apuntador?
Otra cosa, por qué poner (*) x, o , (*) (int)? (poner entre paréntesis el apuntador)

Comment: Por favor. Los comentarios no son para mantener diálogos ni para formular nuevas preguntas. Y ya que estamos, [edita](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/397951/edit) tu pregunta para formular una pregunta real. ¿ Has intentado compilar el código que muestras ? ¿ Te da algún error ? Deberías consultar [¿ Como elaboro una buena pregunta ?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.